# How to intersect Array of objects in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, object

How do i get the result of intersection between two Array of Objects in PHP.

For Example,

the value of **$array1** is

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [influencer_id] => 2
            [follower_id] => 1
        )

)
```

and the value of **$array2** is,

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [influencer_id] => 1
            [follower_id] => 2
        ),
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [influencer_id] => 3
            [follower_id] => 2
        ),

)
```

So, what i want to get in **$result** is

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [influencer_id] => 2
            [follower_id] => 1
        )

)
```

What is the best way to get it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean the object of $array2[0] has the same value of $array1[0]? If  so I think there is a misstyping.

Comment: No. if any element in  $array2 matches with any element with $array1 that should be in the result. note that the elements are object here.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that using [`array_uintersect` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) and defining manually your callback comparison function :

```
$arr1 = json_decode('[{"id":2,"influencer_id":2,"follower_id":1}]');
$arr2 = json_decode('[{"id":2,"influencer_id":2,"follower_id":1},{"id":3,"influencer_id":3,"follower_id":2}]');

$arr3 = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, function ($e1, $e2) { 
    if($e1->id == $e2->id && $e1->influencer_id == $e2->influencer_id && $e1->follower_id == $e2->follower_id) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});

var_dump($arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

> array_intersect() returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are present in all the arguments. Note that keys are preserved.

Comment: It gives this error
"Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: nah comparing objects, read this post for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834607/array-intersect-for-object-array-php